# Grep in MySQL CLI interpretter

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Is there any way to grep the output of the MySQL interpretter (CentOS 5.x)? For instance, I know that I need a table with "user" in the table name. Ideally, I would love something like this:

```
DESCRIBE TABLES; | grep "user"
```

I know that I can exit MySQL and then do it in bash:

```
mysql -u me -p "USE someTable; DESCRIBE TABLES;" | grep "user"
```

But I would prefer to stay in MySQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Give this a try!

```
mysql> pager grep user
PAGER set to 'grep user'
mysql> USE someTable;
mysql> DESCRIBE TABLES;
```

I've just tried it with Mysql v5.0.83, and it does what you would think ;)

Comment: Thank you, that is absolutely terrific!

Comment: hint: disable it with nopager

Comment: one can also pipe grep to real pager like less: `pager grep user | less`

Comment: Works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter tables with a like

show tables like '%user%';